# When I published the web in vs2012," The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I published the web in vs2012," The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
But when I generation solution, it's not wrong and it works.

Comment: Are you using Nuget packages?

Comment: You published the web? All of it?

Comment: When you say you "published", you mean you put the output of the Publish command in a web server (e.g. IIS) and it's showing you this error?

Comment: by generated the solution you mean built it? publish also checks your razor view pages where as build only checks c# files